# Is there a way to monitor heap usage in C++/MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I fear that some of my code is causing memory leaks, and I'm not sure about how to check it. Is there a tool or something for MacOS X?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a good description of how to use MallocDebug on OS X on their developer pages.

- document on [finding leaks](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html) in general
- [enabling debug features of malloc](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) in particular.

Comment: Alas, the links are dead.

Answer (score 5):

Yes - there's an application called **MallocDebug** which is installed as part of the Xcode package.

You can find it in the `/Developer/Applications/Performance Tools` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Of course UNIX provides a quick and dirty way of detecting memory leaks... top.

Launch your app and watch the system memory allocated to your process over time. If it continually grows when it shouldn't then there is likely a memory leak. At which point you break out [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or use MallocDebug, etc.

Of course if you use smart pointers and/or RAII, then you shouldn't have memory leaks in your code, right? ;)))

Comment: Yes, in fact I'm trying to check if my implementation of smart pointers is working correctly :)

Comment: Any reason for not using boost::scoped_ptr or boost::shared_ptr ??

Answer (score 0):

THE BEST tool PERIOD for memory errors, leaks, etc. is Valgrind. Get started [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/QuickStart.html). You dont need to do anything special in your code and this will report where the memory was allocated (with a full stack trace, even in C). Also, it'll detect writes to freed memory, uninitialized memory usage, and much more.